# Editing data in EXCEL sheet using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a excel with multiple columns which contains address fields. I want that address line to be in proper case. When I am able to get them in proper case, some words like `1st`,`2nd`,`SW(South West)`,`10th` etc., are transforming into `1St`, `2Nd`, `Sw`, `10Th`. I need python code to resolve this.

```
addr_df['ADDRESS1'] = addr_df.apply(set_propercase_fn,args=("Address1",), axis=1)
```

with the above code I am able to get the data in proper case. I tried using below code to make possible changes, It did work but not appropriate.

```
def replacestring(val):
    reps = {'Parker':'Borker', '1St':'st', 'Sw':'SW', 'S W':'SW'}
    for i,j in reps.items():
        if i in val: val = val.replace(i,j)
return val
print(addr_df['ADDRESS1'].apply(replacestring))
```

Comment: What does your current code (with the bug) looks like? How can we fix a bug we can't see?

Comment: addr_df['ADDRESS1'] = addr_df.apply(set_propercase_fn,args=("Address1",), axis=1)

Comment: Please fix your code formatting by using correct indentation and code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) it is a great tool, been using it for a long time. With this tool you can modify each and every cell of an excel file.